# Determine how many memory slots are available in a specific computer?

Tags: memory, hex, 32bit-64bit, ram

Im studying assembly langauge on my own with a textbook, and I have a question that talks about the memory of a computer. It says the possible memory in a 32-bit PC is 4,294,967,296, which is 4GB. This is because the last memory location is FFFFFFFF base 16 (8 F's there). It also goes on to say that 2^10 is 1KB, 2^30 is 1GB etc. It also addresses 64-bit machines, saying 64 bit mode can internally store 64-bit addresses and "that at the time this book was written, processors use at most 48 bits of the possible 64". It goes on to say that this limitation is no match, because it could address up to 2^48 bytes of physical memory (256TB) which is 65,536 times the maximum in 32-bit systems. It also finally talks about RAM and how it basically provides an extension of memory. Okay okay, so I just wanted to tell you what my book has been telling me, and so it possesses a questions:

Suppose that you buy a 64-bit PC with 2 GB of RAM. What is the 16-hex-digit of the "last" byte of installed memory?

And I tried to tackle it by saying we know from the boook that 2^30 = 1GB and I said, 2^x = 2GB. I then knew that one physical address is one byte, so I converted 2GB to the respective  amount of bytes. I then I took the log of base 2 of how many bytes I got to solve for x. I got 2^31 in the end, but that was a lot of work. I then converted it to hex giving me 80000000 base 16. And I was stumped then. I look at the answer in the back of the book and it says this:

2 * 3^20 = 2^31 = 80000000 base 16, so the last address is 000000007FFFFFFF.

how did the book get 3^20? and that doesnt even equal 2^31 when you times it all out by 2. How do you solve this problem.

In addition how does RAM correspond to memory, is it an extension of the physical memory? the book doesnt actually say that, just says its wiped from the computer every time the computer shuts off, etc. Could you give me more insight on this?

Thanks,
-Dan

Comment: what's your book? How about giving a name so that I can check the original content about that. Now I prefer it's a mistake of this book.

Comment: It's a typo. 2^31 = 2 * 2^30 of course.

Comment: The book is called "Introduction to 80x86 Assembly Language and Computer Architecture"